Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{(2n)!}$
I'm looking if there's a general closed form for the following function:
$$
f(k) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{(2n)!},
$$
for $k\in \Bbb{N}$.
For specific $k$ values I can utilize the fact that
$$
\cosh(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
$$
by repeated differentiation and solving for the desired sum.
For example, for $f(3)$, we differentiate $\cosh(x)$ three times (and evaluate it at $x=1$) and obtain:
$$
\cosh(1) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{8n^3-12n^2+4n}{(2n)!} = 8\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(2n)!}-12\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!}+4\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(2n)!}.
$$
Rearranging and utilizing the following equalities:
$$
-12\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(2n)!} = -3(\cosh(1)+\sinh(1)-2) 
$$
and
$$
4\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(2n)!} = 2\sinh(1)-2,
$$
we obtain that
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(2n)!} = \frac{3\cosh(1)+2\sinh(1)-4}{8}.
$$
Lastly, we add $\frac{1}{2}$ to both sides to finish:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(2n)!} = \frac{3\cosh(1)+2\sinh(1)}{8}.
$$
However, this technique really begins to get tedious and I am not seeing an obvious pattern to find a closed form. Any direction or advice would be appreciated. Alternatively, I really want to show that there exists some function $g(n)$ such that
$$
\sum_{i,j\in \Bbb{N}}\frac{(8\pi^2)^{i+j}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{i+j}}{g(n)}}{i!j!} < \infty.
$$
I've tried $g(n)=n!$ and that failed, therefore, the next natural guess would be $(2n)!$. However, that seems much more difficult at first glance.

Do you mean $2(n!)$ or $(2n)!$ Mathematicians read $2n!$ as $2(n!),$ but it looks like you mean $(2n)!$ If so, fix your question.

$$ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left(e^x T_n(x) + e^{-x} T_n(-x) \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$$ with $T_n(x)$ The touchard polynomials.

Following up on @DecarbonatedOdes's observation, one has $T_n(1)=B_n$ as the Bell numbers (OEIS A0001110). The case of $T_n(-1)$ is less standard but appears to be tabulated as OEIS A000587.

If the connection wasn't clear:$$ \frac{1}{2^n} \left( \cosh(1) \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\brace 2k}  + \sinh(1)  \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\brace 2k+1}  \right) $$ with $n\brace k$ the Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind.

If we define for a polynomial $p$ $$F_p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{p(n)}{n!}x^n$$ then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{p(2n)}{(2n)!}=\frac12\left(F_p(1)+F_p(-1)\right)$$
In your case, $p_k(x)=\frac{x^k}{2^k}.$ But this is tricky.
We will instead solve this first for the falling factorials, instead, $q_k(x)=x(x-1)\cdots(x-(k-1)).$
Then $F_{q_k}(x)=x^ke^x.$ Then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q_k(2n)}{(2n)!}=\frac12\left(e+(-1)^ke^{-1}\right)$$ with the right side $\sinh(1)$ when $k$ odd and $\cosh(1)$ when $k$ even.
Then you need to write $p_k(x)$ as a linear combination of the $q_k.$
For example, $$p_3(x)=\frac{x^3}{8}=\frac18q_3(x)+\frac38 q_2(x)+\frac18q_1(x)$$
Then $$\sum \frac{n^3}{(2n)!}=\frac18\sinh 1+\frac38\cosh 1+\frac18\sinh1=\frac14\sinh1+\frac38\cosh1.$$
Finding $p_k$ in terms of the $q_k$ can be done automatically fairly easily, since the $q_k$ are monic of degree $k.$
There are theorems giving these coefficients, but I am forgetting them off the top of my head, having something to do,with Stirling number, I think.
I think for $k=4$ you get $$\frac{x^4}{16}=\frac1{16}q_4+\frac6{16}q_3+\frac{7}{16}q_2+\frac1{16}q_1,$$ and thus you get: $$\sum\frac{n^4}{(2n)!}=\frac12\cosh1+\frac7{16}\sinh 1.$$
For $k=5,$ I get $\frac{27}{32}\sinh1+\frac{25}{32}\sinh 1.$

I am doubtful that there is too pleasant a "general closed form" for the sum about which you are asking. (I am assuming that your denominator is $(2n)!$ and not $2\cdot n!$ which is how it currently appears.)
Checking just the first few values of these suggests that you end up with:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{(2n)!} = \frac{1}{2^k}\big(A \sinh(1) + B\cosh(1)\big)$$
where $A$ is the $k^\text{th}$ term from A024429 and $B$ is the $k^\text{th}$ term from A024430.
Those OEIS pages have further links around the exponential generating functions for $\sinh(e^x - 1)$ and $\cosh(e^x - 1)$, respectively. Although putting these pieces together may not amount to much in terms of novelty, it does indicate that closed form for your sum is equivalent to closed form for these egf's.

See, in particular, Table 1 on p. 276 [PDF 3/8] in the paper here. The linked paper is Fekete's "Apropos Bell and Stirling Numbers."
